# Managing groups in a Google Apps Domain from a GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-groups

I'm developing an app using Python and Google App Engine. It's an app to be executed in a domain powered by Google Apps for Business.

One of most important things I have to take into account are the ACLs (Access Control Lists). I mean, if the logged user is a Head of Division, for example, he/she can see "more things" than a common employee.

What is the best way to manage that? Google Groups? Which API should I check?

**UPDATE**: Maybe is not a problem to solve with programming, but with configuration parameters. Am i right? http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2370108

Thanks in advance